# Undefined reference to `readimagefile'

Tags: c++, bgi

I'm having a problem when compiling the code below it says "undefined reference to 'readimagefile'" and it's moving me to another page or something I don't know.  [image: page idk] I've included all the libraries needed to run the code and the photo is in the same folder where the code is located. Please help I've researched a lot and I can't find a solution. Thank you!

```
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    initwindow(800,600);

    readimagefile("alien.jpg",0,0,200,200);

    getch();
    closegraph();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: If possible learn to use something a few decades newer than BGI. It will more closely reflect what is used by programmers today. In addition, even if you get this to compile and link odds are the program sitill won't work because most BGI ports are too old to handle modern OSes and hardware. [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/) and [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/) both contain modern graphics libraries. [SDLBGI](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/) is BGI rebuilt to function over top of SDL if you MUST use BGI.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I will try SMFL